# Entity Framework Core Include then Take 2

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1

For **learning purpose** i made a console application using EFCore 3.1

i have relationship like this:

> **Person** belongs To one **Type**
>
> **Person** have many **Queries**
>
> **Query** belongs to one **Person**
>
> **Query** belongs to a **Location**

this Console application is connected to a Mysql DB Scaffolded into **Entities** with Pomelo.

Now i need to get every **Persons** from the DB then his related **Type** and Last **Queries** ordered by date, each person have hundreds queries and there is thousands persons on this db, so if i try to

```
using (var ctx = new DBContext) 
{
    var persons = ctx.Persons
                  .Include(p => p.Type)
                  .Include(p => p.Queries).ThenInclude(q => q.Location)
}
```

it will timeout because he's trying to get every queries for each person, like it should be, because i read somewhere in another answer that with the include it's all or nothing.

In my DB i have a double linked view for this purpose, one for get the max_query_id (person_maxquery) for each person_id and one for joining this 4 tables

```
SELECT p.*, ty.*, pq.*, loc.* FROM persons p
LEFT JOIN person_maxquery max ON p.id = max.person_id
LEFT JOIN person_queries pq ON pq.id = max.query_id
LEFT JOIN locations loc ON loc.id = pq.location_id
LEFT JOIN types ty ON ty.id = p.type_id
```

I want to achieve the same thing in EF but i didn't know if this is possible, could i filter data got from DB? Should i "make" my object using the view manually assigning every value to related model value?

Comment: Just use EF joins, it will do it on the DB and return only the exact set

Comment: he will also fill entities? I mean, could i access to Person.Type.id after getting persons with join? And how i can replicate the db query i wrote in mysql in ef?considering that it has an intermediate table (person_maxquery) i didn't know how to write it

Comment: maybe include a where or a take.. if you want to filter... ur query as is just pulls everything, obviously it going to time out

Comment: @Seabizkit that's what i want to achieve, but i can't use LINQ method in Include (or at least this is what VS say to me when i try to do that), it would have been awesome if i could use something like: Persons.Include(p => p.Queries.Take(2))

Comment: oh i see, but are you still wanting for all users,  mean doing ` var persons = ctx.Persons
                  .Include(p => p.Type)
                  .Include(p => p.Queries).ThenInclude(q => q.Location).where(x=>x.PersonId == id)` would reduce the time drastically.

Comment: @Seabizkit i need to cycle through all Persons, so every person should be instantiate, what take time is acquiring for each person hundreds of Queries, so maybe i could use where to take just the "lastQuery" but how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Queries that pull sets of data rarely need the entire details from the applicable entities. You can mitigate this and filter data by projecting the entities to a view model structure that reflects what data you really need.

```
using (var ctx = new DBContext) 
{
    var persons = ctx.Persons
        .Select(x => new PersonViewModel
        {
           PersonId = x.PersonId,
           Name = x.Name,
           TypeName = x.Type.Name,
           RecentQueries = x.Queries
               .OrderByDecending(q => q.QueryDate)
               .Select(q => new QueryViewModel
               {
                  QueryId = q.QueryId,
                  Name = q.Name,
                  LocationName = q.Location.Name
                  // ... etc.
               }).Take(2).ToList()
        }).ToList();
    //...
}
```

This approach helps build more efficient queries with just the data you need. Pulling full entity graphs is more of a per-item request such as when applying an update to a person and their related entities rather than trying to pull back all people with all, or a subset of their related entities.

Edit: Example lifecycle of some data between server and view:

Part 1... List a bunch of people. These are summaries, enough data to satisfy a summary list view.

```
public IEnumerable<PersonSummaryViewModel> GetPeople(/*criteria*/)
{
    using (var ctx = new DBContext) 
    {
        var people = ctx.Persons
            .Where( /* based on criteria */ )
            .Select(x => new PersonSummaryViewModel
            {
               PersonId = x.PersonId,
               Name = x.Name,
               TypeName = x.Type.Name,
               RecentQueries = x.Queries
                   .OrderByDecending(q => q.QueryDate)
                   .Select(q => new QuerySummaryViewModel
                   {
                      QueryId = q.QueryId,
                      Name = q.Name,
                      LocationName = q.Location.Name
                      // ... etc.
                   }).Take(2).ToList()
            }).ToList();
        //...
        return people;
    }
}
```

Part 2: Get a Person Detailed Model. Once a user selects a person, we will want to pull back more data. This view model can have a lot more fields and relationships to satisfy the view. But even here we may want to exclude data that is not commonly viewed, (such as in expandable regions or tabs) that can be pulled back on demand with Ajax calls if/when the user wants.

```
public PersonDetailViewModel> GetPerson(int personId)
{
    using (var ctx = new DBContext) 
    {
        var person = ctx.Persons
            .Select(x => new PersonDetailViewModel
            {
               PersonId = x.PersonId,
               Name = x.Name,
               TypeName = x.Type.Name,
               // ... Can load all visible properties and initial, important related data...
            }).Single(x => x.PersonId == personId);
        //...
        return person;
    }
}
```

Part 3: Example, Update a Person

```
public void UpdatePerson(UpdatePersonViewModel updatePersonModel)
{
    if (updatePersonModel == null)
       throw new ArgumentNullException("updatePersionModel");

    // TODO: Validate updateModel, ensure everything is Ok, not tampered/invalid.
    using (var ctx = new DBContext) 
    {
        var person = ctx.Persons
            // can .Include() any related entities that can be updated here...
            .Where( x => x.PersonId == updatePersonModel.PersonId )
            .Single();
        person.Name = updatePersonModel.Name;
        // etc.
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Part 4: Example, add a Query.

```
public void AddQuery(int personId, AddQueryViewModel queryModel)
{
    if (queryModel == null)
       throw new ArgumentNullException("queryModel");

    // TODO: Validate queryModel, ensure everything is Ok, not tampered/invalid.
    using (var ctx = new DBContext) 
    {
        var person = ctx.Persons
            .Include( x => x.Queries )
            .Where( x => x.PersonId == personId )
            .Single();

        // TODO: Maybe check for duplicate query already on Person, etc.
        var query = new Query
        {
            // copy data from view model
        };
        person.Queries.Add(query);
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

The view models (or DTOs) only relate to transmitting data between the server and the client. When we get data back to the server and want to update entities, we load those entities. By using these view models we reduce the amount of data sent between client and server (just the fields needed, not entire entity graphs) which means faster code and less data over the wire. We don't expose more about our entity structure than the client needs to know, and we don't risk simply overwriting data coming back by something like `Attach` + `EntityState.Modified` + `SaveChanges` where the data could be stale (someone else modified since that copy was taken) or the data coming back could be tampered with. View models are single purpose. We could use a PersonDetailViewModel in an UpdatePerson type operation but our update may only apply to a select few properties so there is the overhead of sending everything back to the server, and no implied restriction on what should, and should not be allowed to be updated. (Especially if you use Automapper or such to help copy fields back and forth between entities and view models)

In cases where we just want to interact with some entity data, without sending it back to the client, we don't need view models/DTOs, we can just selectively retrieve fields from the entire entity graph using Anonymous Types. For instance if I just want to check if a person has a certain matching criteria and summarize the query names that match:

```
var queryNames = ctx.Persons
    .Where(x => x.PersonId == personId)
    .SelectMany(x => Queries.Select( q => new  
    {
       q.QueryId,
       q.Name
    }).ToList();
var message = string.Join(", ", 
    queryNames.Select(x => string.Format("{0} ({1})", x.Name, x.QueryId)));
```

Just as a simple example with an anonymous type to return a structure that can be used by further code without the need for a view model / DTO. We're not passing the entity data back, but perhaps just inspecting values to determine a course of action, or composing something like a message string.

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for your answer. What type will be persons after that? a List<Persons> or a List<PersonViewModel> ? I'm asking this because i already have lots of methods that use Persons model, so if I pass them a different model it will be necessary to change all the code.

Comment: This would return the PersonViewModel. Passing entities around can be problematic from a performance & resource perspective, plus if you pass entities to a client you expose everything about your domain models (beyond what your views display) and accepting entities back leaves you vulnerable to stale data overwrites plus data tampering.  So it is a bit of a trade off: using entities will lead to potential performance and security implications. Passing view models will be faster/safer but require extra classes for transport.

Comment: So your advice is to take data into a viewmodel even if I don’t need to display it, but just update/doing some operation with it, then pass it again to a entities to interact with the database?

Comment: No, when dealing with updating a single element I would load the entity and any applicable related ones. When loading a list of data though, like this example, I would use View Models. Something like the PersonViewModel or a PersonSummaryViewModel would represent each of the list sent to the client. If the client wants to apply an update and send that back then it composes a PersonUpdateViewModel with the ID & relevant updates. The server loads a single Person and related entities using the ID then copies the values across after validating. Tools like automapper can help copy data between.

Comment: I've expanded on the answer to outline an example of a typical data flow where view models might be used, and where they wouldn't be needed.

Comment: Thanks Steve for the explanation, really appreciate.